# Change a key function for x amount of time?

Tags: toggle, autohotkey

So thanks to this [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9253414) i have got this working code, but i want to further tweak it if its posibble. :D

*Here is the code:*

```
global s:=0, c:=0, t:=1500, t2:=380

*lbutton::
    send % Seqkeys("5","6")
    KeyWait, lbutton
    If (A_TickCount-s < t2)
        c := 0
    Send, 7
return

Seqkeys(params*) { 
    global s, c, t
    max := params.MaxIndex()
    (A_TickCount-s<=t && (c+=1)<=max) ? c : c:=1
    s := A_TickCount
    return params[c]
}
```

What i want to implement is that if i hit the right mouse button (Rbutton), the original lbutton seqkeys code changes to this code for 1 second

```
*lbutton::
    send, 8
    KeyWait, lbutton
    Send, 7
return
```

than when the 1 sec is over the code is revert back to the original seqkeys state.

I got this code sample but its not working properly for several reasons, when i hit the Rbutton it does override the original Seqkeys function, but it never resets back to the seqkeys one. I put it here maybe it helps

```
*rbutton::
toggle:=true
return

#If Toggle
*lbutton::
    send, 8
    KeyWait, lbutton
    Send, 7
return
toggle:=false
Return
#If
```

Thx again! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it never reset back to `Seqkeys(params*)` after toggle is that `toggle:=false` is outside the toggled lbutton hotkey. 
Putting it inside toggle lbutton hotkey before the `return` statement fixes the issue.

```
#If Toggle
*lbutton::
    send, 8
    KeyWait, lbutton
    Send, 7
    toggle:=false
return
```

Comment: thank you! its working well. i just need 1 more thing to be my perfect script :D if u dont mind.

So i press the rbutton and if i dont hit lbutton it would would reset itself after 1 sec to the Seqkeys(params*) either way even if i dont hit the lbutton.

Comment: so with this code i managed to revert it back to the original state after 1 sec 

rbutton::
toggle:=true
SetTimer, lbutton, -1000
return

but it sends the lbutton after 1 sec. basicly it pressing itself. i dont want it to press itself. want it to reset to Seqkeys(params*) after 1 sec without pressing it. but of course if i want to press it under 1 sec it should be posibble to be pressed.

Comment: Adding `KeyWait, lbutton, D T1` followed by `if ErrorLevel{ toggle:=false}` inside the `*rbutton` hotkey and after the `toggle:=true` will reset it to `Seqkeys()`

Comment: it gives me an error message Unexpected ({) when i put the `KeyWait, lbutton, D T1` and if `ErrorLevel{ toggle:=false}` inside rbutton. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: try to put `ErrorLevel`, braces and `toggle:= false` on separate lines.